# Is it possible to convert a numeric data type into a string for output in Java?

Tags: java, string, methods, return, numeric

I'm a beginner programmer looking to tweak a project. I did not include code as I have no clue where to start. Basically, I'm capturing input for different airline ticket classes. Such as: type 1 for 1st class, 2 for business, and 3 for economy. Then the input is run through if else statements to determine the cost of each ticket depending on the class. After the price is figured out and passed to another method for calculation with discount rate, I want to display the class type in the output window.

For further clarity it would say something like, (name + "Your class type is: " + classType + "Your discount price is: " + discountPrice + "Your finalPrice is:" + finalPrice).....plus all the formatting elegance. I would like classType to display the actual word instead of just "1" "2" or "3". I've been able to, at least, capture the input and assign prices then calculate. I just wish after doing this that I could return a string value instead of the numeric type. To those who help, thank you much and please remember I'm a noob and haven't had the opportunity to learn arrays and anything more complicated than that.

Comment: you want 1 to be printed as one and 100 to be printed as one hundred? Is this your question

Comment: Yes and no. 1 is assigned to first class. So instead of "1" being displayed for classType, I would like "first class" to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a simple enough scenario, you can do something like this:

```
int typeNum; // This is what holds 1, 2, 3 etc for the type of ticket
             // 0 is used, so we'll just put a "NONE" as the string for it
String classType[] = {"NONE", "First Class", "Business", "Economy"};
...
System.out.println(name + 
                   "Your class type is: " + classType[typeNum] + 
                   "Your discount price is: " + discountPrice + 
                   "Your finalPrice is:" + finalPrice);
```

The "**proper**" way to do a type-to-string mapping (and just using types in general) is to use `enum`'s: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

(**Update**): As requested for a way to do this without arrays:

```
int typeNum; // Still the int that should be either 1, 2, or 3 for type of ticket
...

String classType;

if ( typeNum == 1 ) {
    classType = "First Class";
} else if ( typeNum == 2 ) {
    classType = "Business";
} else if ( typeNum == 3 ) {
    classType = "Economy";
} else {
    classType = "(Unrecognized Ticket Type)";
}

System.out.println(name + 
                   "Your class type is: " + classType + 
                   "Your discount price is: " + discountPrice + 
                   "Your finalPrice is:" + finalPrice);
```

Comment: +1 For a low-tech solution my first thought was a switch/assignment, but an array is much more clever.

Comment: Now bear with me here. I'm not quite understanding classType[] assigned to a string...is this an array or am I really that fresh? I'm focusing on just using multiple methods, invoking them and returning a value to be displayed in the main method. Can I return a string and a value from the method used to assign a price to the class type?

Comment: @BenignBaboon Yup, `classType` is an array of Strings. For example, `classType[1]` will be `"First Class"`, `classType[2]` will be "Business", and so on.

Comment: @BenignBaboon You cannot return a string AND a value - because that would be trying to return 2 variables, and Java only lets you return 1 variable from a function. Moreover, the function is declared as `public static double classTypePrice(...`, so it must return a `double`. However, you can convert the value, after it's been returned , to a string - so that's not a problem.

Comment: I'm sure this will work fine and I thank you for taking the time, however, I was wondering if there was a way to do this without arrays. I may be getting too far in head of myself.

Comment: @BenignBaboon you can do it with a if-elseif block, or a switch statement. I'll add an example of how to do it with if-elseif in my answer.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. It looks so simple now that it's displayed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your class type seems like a good candidate for an `enum`. For example:

```
public enum ClassType {

    FIRST_CLASS(1, "1st Class"),
    BUSINESS(2, "Business"),
    ECONOMY(3, "Economy");

    private final int code;
    private final String name;

    private ClassType(int code, String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static ClassType getByCode(int code) {
        for (ClassType classType : ClassType.values()) {
            if (classType.code == code) {
                return classType;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

In case you haven't learned about enums yet, a good place to start is the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).